# css to properly align text right to left in a block

Tags: css, text-alignment

I have been trying to format arabic text direction in a block from right to left using the following css:
`.MatchingV1_1 { max-width: 100%; float: left; text-align: right; direction: rtl; }`

but the result is that if the line does not wrap within the block (because it is just a few words), it is then aligned to the left. If the line wraps, it is aligned to the right.

Any suggestions to "concur" this problem?
 Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you put your whole page css/html on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap a div over it. **[DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/2RuUD/1/)**

```
<div class="MatchingV1_1">أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة</div>

.MatchingV1_1 {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Venom Vendor, "MatchingV1_1" is actually wrapped in a span as per this: `<a id="bd584947-a9b2-bee0-a230-f96885a0472a" class="responselabeldynamic" href="#" style="top: 10px; left: 10px;"><span class="MatchingV1_1" id="">هذا هو النص الذي أريد أن أعدله من اليسار إلى اليمين</span></a>`, and still if the number of words exceeds the line and wraps, it is aligned to right, otherwise it defaults to left alignment.

Comment: @JosefMiller It seems working, you can delete some text in the DEMO & try.

Comment: Sure, it works in the DEMO, now I have to apply it on my script. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove float property or add float:right in css**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E8rhm/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="MatchingV1_1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="MatchingV1_2">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.MatchingV1_1 {
    max-width: 100%;
    /*float: left;*/
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
.MatchingV1_2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Adding float is not a wise solution, it may misplace the div.

Comment: I agree, The Arabic version is exactly reverse of English version in point of view css. It's depend upon the layout where we add which property. That's the reason I will give you both the suggestions. Currently remove float property works for you.

Comment: Thanks Maysam, in fact `float:` does not have any effect on the text whether it is `left` or `right` which is adding to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your container `div` does not have a `width`:

```
.MatchingV1_1 { max-width: 100%;
    float: left; 
    text-align: right; 
    direction: rtl; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/KwLWm/

Comment: Thanks Maysam, in fact `float:` doesn't have much effect on the text alignment whether it is `left` or `right`. I actually tried both and still didn't work.

Comment: @JosefMiller even width?